# How to perform a delay on a non-UI Thread in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, handler

So, there are multiple similar questions/answers about how to do a delay on Android. However they mostly focus on doing this on UI thread.
What if I need a delay in a worker thread in a service (and I don't want to put the thread to sleep)? the Handler.postDelayed() doesn't work as there is a "can't create a handler inside thread has not called Looper.prepare()" exception. CountDownTimer doesn't work for the same reason. And I don't have any views to call runOnUiThread().
So is the only solution to have a looper on each thread I have or there is another way to do this?

UPDATE:
It's silly, but I found the answer working for me in my own old code :).
Basically, if you want to start a Runnable with a delay from a non-UI thread, all you need to do is ask the main looper to handle this.

```
    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
        // Do stuff to be run after a delay
        // CAUTION: this won't be run on the same thread
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(r, DELAY_TIME);
```

The drawback could be that the code in that Runnable will not be run on the same thread as the original code. This is why I'm not putting this approach as an answer to be accepted (I admit, the original question sounded like I want a timed event to happen on the same non-UI thread. For this I don't have an answer yet except the one from Emmanuel that I must attach a Looper to my thread). For my purposes however this works as I only need to start a service upon timeout.

Comment: The error message *can't create a handler inside thread has not called Looper.prepare()* is self explanatory. You need to call `Looper.prepare()` in the oncreate.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I'm not trying to fix this error here. I'm looking for an alternative approach to have a delay without using Handler/Looper pair.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like you have seen from the `Exceptions` in order to use `Handlers` in a `Thread` you need to attach the `Thread` to the `Looper`. To give a bit more context, when you call `postDelay()` you are posting a message to the `Thread`'s  `MessageQueue`; the `Looper` is responsible for managing this `Queue`. So if you want to go the `Handler` route you will need to set up the `Thread` with a `Looper`.

If you want to delay the `Thread` without making it `sleep()` (I do not know why you cannot use `sleep()`) you can have a `while` that runs until a certain time from now has elapsed. (This sounds like a horrible idea).

Comment: Yeah, this was my understanding as well, but I wanted to check if someone knows a way. The reason I don't want to put it to sleep (and even worse make a while(true)) is because I want this delay to be asynchronous and non-blocking. Say at some point in the flow I want to send an intent. However I'd like to do it not right away, but after, say, one second.

Comment: I am not sure yet. I'm looking for ways alternative to attaching a handler to every thread. Emmanuel pretty much says it's impossible. I'd like to hear more opinions. (actually, I'm including my own too for discussion)